# How do I get the difference in minutes between two dates in SSIS using Derived Column transform?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, ssis, expression

I'd like to get the difference in minutes between two dates in **SSIS** using the Derived Column tranformation. I have a working **SQL Server 2008** script below but I can't successfully convert it to an expression in the Derived Column transform. Any help is appreciated.

```
(floor((CONVERT(float, CAST(dm.DLVRY_DAT AS DATETIME)) - CONVERT(float, CAST(ch.BOOKING_DATE AS DATETIME))) * 24) * 60) + 
(((CONVERT(float, CAST(dm.DLVRY_DAT AS DATETIME)) - CONVERT(float, CAST(ch.BOOKING_DATE AS DATETIME))) * 24 - floor((CONVERT(float, CAST(dm.DLVRY_DAT AS DATETIME)) - CONVERT(float, CAST(ch.BOOKING_DATE AS DATETIME))) * 24)) * 60)
```

SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT) --> this works in SQL but when converted to SSIS expression in the Derived Column transform ((DT_R8) GETDATE()) this does not work.

Please guide me how to do it in SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(DT_I4)DATEDIFF("Minute",(DT_DATE)BookingDate,(DT_DATE)DeliverDate)
```

Also, note that you could use the following in SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, BookingDate, DeliverDate)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the idea! Will try this and run against different dates.  I read some comments that there were some issues on using datediff to get the difference between dates. Maybe that was before SQL Server 2008.